# error with border on the left hand side in google chrome and safari?

Tags: css

I have recently launched a site built on word press using a heavily edited child theme of the twenty ten theme, the problem is when viewed in google chrome or safari a small portion of the left hand border on the sidebar sat on the left is displaying the wrong colour. Its not a big issue and it goes away when you scroll to the bottom of the page, its more annoying than anything just wondering if any one else had encountered this.

I am using different colour borders to get the pressed in effect if this matters.

The site is located at [www.paintedroom.co.uk](http://www.paintedroom.co.uk)

Comment: i don't see the problem, maybe post a screenshot to show what you mean?

Comment: you get solved this issues?? i also dont see the problem...

Comment: Seems to be a webkit bug. If you scroll the page, the error disappears

Comment: Thank you all for swift replies, does anyone know a work around to prevent this annoying bug

Comment: I'm afraid I do not have the rep to post images or screen shots

Comment: I have found what is causing this bug it is the border-radius property. when removed the bug goes away still not sure how to fix though.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but some of the "less standard" CSS properties are implemented on a per-browser basis, with a browser-specific prefix. For example, the `transform` property is `-moz-transform` in Firefox, `-o-transform` in Opera, and `-webkit-transform` in Safari and Chrome.

Comment: I am using the vendor specific prefixes for older versions and the bug is still there. Has anyone else experianced it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what is causing this bug it is the border-radius property. when removed the bug goes away still not sure how to fix though.